# First goroutine example, weird results

Tags: go, goroutine

This example taken from [tour.golang.org/#63](http://tour.golang.org/#63)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
    say("hello")
}
```

#### The output

```
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
```

Why `world` is printed only `4` times instead of `5` ?

---

**Edit:** The answer can be quoted from [golang specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When the function main returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to
>   complete.

Comment: It must be a bug local to that presentation. I can not reproduce this on `gccgo 4.7.2`

Comment: @NlightNFotis I get the same behaviour as in the question on the tour.golang.org (see link in the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your main function ends your program ends, i.e. all goroutines are terminated.
Your main terminates before `go say("world")` is done.  If you sleep some time at the end of main you should see the last world.

Comment: I come from the `java` world :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you solve that synchronization problem properly - with [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/VDubcF6Rh9)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func say(s string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(2)
    go say("world", wg)
    go say("hello", wg)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All done")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the calling gorouting terminates before the second one you spawned does. This causes the second to shut down. To illustrate, modify your code slightly:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Print(i)
        fmt.Println(":"+s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
    say("hello")
}
```

Try putting in a "wait" or a sleep to the end of the main function.