# Prevent the main() function from terminating before goroutines finish in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, program-entry-point, goroutine

Have  loook at this contrived example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printElo() {
    fmt.Printf("Elo\n")
}

func printHello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello\n")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("This will print.")
    i := 0
    for i < 10 {
        go printElo()
        go printHello()
        i++
    }
}
```

The output of this program would be just "This will print". Output of goroutines `printElo()` and `printHello` will not be emitted because, I guess, the `main()` function thread will finish before the goroutines have a chance to even start executing.

What is the idiomatic way to make similar code work in Golang and not terminate prematurely?

Comment: [this blogpost](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/) captures different approaches. 1. using a channel that goroutines write to and main reads from, 2. using [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). There's also [this s/o answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18601301/1520594) for reference.

Comment: @algrebe As noted by the article's reviewer and seconded by the author himself - both approaches described in the article originally are "dangerously inaccurate" so they cannot really constitute an answer to this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simplest, cleanest and "scalable" way to do it is to use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup):

```
var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}

func printElo() {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("Elo\n")
}

func printHello() {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("Hello\n")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("This will print.")
    i := 0
    for i < 10 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go printElo()
        wg.Add(1)
        go printHello()
        i++
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6L64RRPEW1)):

```
This will print.Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
Hello
Elo
```

Simple "rules" to follow when doing it with `sync.WaitGroup`:

- call [`WaitGroup.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Add) in the "original" goroutine (that starts a new) before the [`go`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) statement
- recommended to call [`WaitGroup.Done()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Done) deferred, so it gets called even if the goroutine panics
- if you want to pass `WaitGroup` to other functions (and not use a package level variable), you must pass a pointer to it, else the `WaitGroup` (which is a struct) would be copied, and the `Done()` method called on the copy wouldn't be observed on the original

Comment: Do you think it's a better approach using `var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}` like you did or passing `wg` as a reference as I made in my snippet? If the first one, can you explain? Pretty curious about that.

Comment: @AndreaM16 I used a global var here for simplicity. If complexity of your code / package increases, or you use multiple waitgroups concurrently, then the global variable might not be viable or might make things more complicated than it should be. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @icza also for sc2gears, used it a lot back in the days. Sorry if off topic.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned `sync.WaitGroup` is a right way in production code. But when developing for test and debug purposes you can just add `select{}` statement at the end or the `main()`.

```
func main(){
    go routine()
    ...
    select{}
}
```

`main()` then never returns and you would kill it with for example `Ctrl-C`. It isn't idiomatic, never used in production, but just very quick easy hack when developing.

Comment: For the love of god, never EVER do this. Just spent the last 4 days trying to debug a program that was using over 200% CPU. This was it.

Comment: @DowlandAiello Why?

Comment: What system are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18661952/14020202 says that it would just block and shouldn't consume any CPU.

Comment: Local testing (nothing in prod) indicates that it doesn't use any CPU. The Go compiler source also indicates that the compiler just optimizes it into a blocking case: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d9fd9201ad214e8da769a9338b9d3a5f3e1bc980/src/cmd/compile/internal/walk/select.go#L38

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sync package](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) and take a look at `waitgroups`. You can take a look at a working [Goplayground I set up.](https://play.golang.org/p/du2Pv04HKz)

Essentially

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    )

//Takes a reference to the wg and sleeps when work is done
func printElo(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Printf("Elo\n")
    defer wg.Done()
}

//Takes a reference to the wg and sleeps when work is done
func printHello(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Printf("Hello\n")
    defer wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    //Create a new WaitGroup
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    fmt.Println("This will print.")

    for  i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        //Add a new entry to the waitgroup
        wg.Add(1)
        //New Goroutine which takes a reference to the wg
        go printHello(&wg)
        //Add a new entry to the waitgroup
        wg.Add(1)
        //New Goroutine which takes a reference to the wg
        go printElo(&wg)
    }
    //Wait until everything is done
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to play with results you can use "hack" with waiting for input:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func printElo() {
    fmt.Printf("Elo\n")
}

func printHello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello\n")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("This will print.")
    i := 0
    for i < 10 {
        go printElo()
        go printHello()
        i++
    }

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    reader.ReadString('\n')
}
```

If want to learn how to do synchronization read about sync package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func printElo() {
    fmt.Printf("Elo\n")
    wg.Done()
}

func printHello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello\n")
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {

    fmt.Printf("This will print.")
    i := 0
    for i < 10 {
        wg.Add(2)
        go printElo()
        go printHello()
        i++
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```