# Can't read from a channel in goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

In this piece of code, a goroutine is created and tries to read from a buffered channel.

But the buffer is empty and should block the receiver, but it didn't. It will run but output nothin.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fun(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    //ch <- 1
    go fun(ch)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the buffer is not empty, because you send a value on it:

```
ch <- 1
```

This send operation will not block because the channel is buffered.

Then you launch a goroutine, and the `main()` function ends. And with that, your program ends as well, it does not wait for other non-main goroutines to complete. For details, see [No output from goroutine in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine-in-go/28958240#28958240).

Note that the same thing happens even if you comment out the send operation in `main()`: you launch a goroutine and then `main()` ends along with your app: it does not wait for the other goroutine.

To wait for other goroutines, often a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) is used like this:

```
var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}

func fun(c chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    ch <- 1

    wg.Add(1)
    go fun(ch)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XyfnENIEj5k)):

```
1
```

For details, see [Prevent the main() function from terminating before goroutines finish in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752705/prevent-the-main-function-from-terminating-before-goroutines-finish-in-golang/42753005#42753005)

Comment: thanks! forgot to comment out the ch<-1 in the question though

Comment: @Gabriel Same thing if you comment out the send: the app ends without waiting for the other goroutine.