# Go channel deadlock is not happening

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("hello")
        c <- 10
    }()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

In the above program, I have created a Go routine which is writing to channel c but there is no other go routine which is reading from the channel. Why isnt there a deadlock in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deadlock implies all goroutines being blocked, not just one arbitrary goroutine of your choosing.

The `main` goroutine is simply in a sleep, once that is over, it can continue to run.

If you switch the `sleep` with a `select{}` blocking forever operation, you'll get your deadlock:

```
c := make(chan int)

go func() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    c <- 10
}()

select {}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/n0XOm_d95qU).

See related: [Why there is no error that receiver is blocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750056/why-there-is-no-error-that-receiver-is-blocked/59750111#59750111)

Comment: is the main routine marked as sleepy somewhere in the internal ? thus prevents the deadlock to trigger before the program exits ? the time.Sleep doc does not mention it.

Comment: @mh-cbon I haven't looked into the internals, but a sleep operation cannot take forever (the duration is finite), hence the deadlock detector shouldn't even bother with it.

Comment: @icza so to conclude, if all the go routines are blocked at particular point, then it is a deadlock.

Comment: @Ganeshdip Yes. Blocked means the runtime can prove none of the goroutines will ever get out of the blocking state, so there is no point waiting forever for nothing.

Comment: Just to clarify, the program does contain a deadlock under the generally accepted definition of deadlock (i.e. some part of the program is blocked waiting for something that will never occur). However, go's deadlock detector can only detect if the the entire program is in deadlock. The main thread is not deadlocked and so go's deadlock detector does not report anything.